# Triggers on MYSQL IPAGE

Tags: mysql, triggers

Hi I'm about to import my database stucture from my local database to ipage.

I recieved an error which goes like this:

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near '' at line 3

My the query I used was

```
CREATE TRIGGER `pm_sales_agent_BDEL` BEFORE DELETE ON `pm_sales_agent`
 FOR EACH ROW begin
DELETE FROM `pm_sales_agent_quota` WHERE `fk_sales_agent_id` = OLD.id;
end
```

I have tried query checker which I found in google and but it says the query is fine:
Here is the link: [MySQL Syntax Check](http://www.piliapp.com/mysql-syntax-check/)

What seems to be the problem? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Did you get through with this? Did you find a way to import your trigger in IPage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`begin` and `end` are used to indicate that multiple statements belong together. However you only have one delete statement, therefore the `;` is ending the `create trigger` statement. Then the `end` is confusing MySQL. Either write it like this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER `pm_sales_agent_BDEL` BEFORE DELETE ON `pm_sales_agent`
 FOR EACH ROW 
DELETE FROM `pm_sales_agent_quota` WHERE `fk_sales_agent_id` = OLD.id;
```

or change the delimiter:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER `pm_sales_agent_BDEL` BEFORE DELETE ON `pm_sales_agent`
 FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
DELETE FROM `pm_sales_agent_quota` WHERE `fk_sales_agent_id` = OLD.id;
END $$
DELIMITER ; /*don't forget to change it back*/
```

**UPDATE:**

To address the error

> #1419 - You do not have the SUPER privilege and binary logging is enabled (you *might* want to use the less safe log_bin_trust_function_creators variable)

you have to specify a characteristic of your trigger (or function). A characteristic can be

- [NOT] DETERMINISTIC
- CONTAINS SQL
- NO SQL
- READS SQL DATA
- MODIFIES SQL DATA

From the manual:

> A routine is considered “deterministic” if it always produces the same result for the same input parameters, and “not deterministic” otherwise. If neither DETERMINISTIC nor NOT DETERMINISTIC is given in the routine definition, the default is NOT DETERMINISTIC. To declare that a function is deterministic, you must specify DETERMINISTIC explicitly.

---

> CONTAINS SQL indicates that the routine does not contain statements that read or write data. This is the default if none of these characteristics is given explicitly. Examples of such statements are SET @x = 1 or DO RELEASE_LOCK('abc'), which execute but neither read nor write data.

---

> NO SQL indicates that the routine contains no SQL statements.

---

> READS SQL DATA indicates that the routine contains statements that read data (for example, SELECT), but not statements that write data.

---

> MODIFIES SQL DATA indicates that the routine contains statements that may write data (for example, INSERT or DELETE).

Read more about it [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-procedure.html).

Also, in case you want to ensure some data integrity with your code, you should have a look at `ON DELETE CASCADE` option of foreign keys.
It deletes data from child tables when you delete data from a parent table.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the response! I really appreciated it!
As for the changes you made on the query snippet, mysql gives another error:
`
 MySQL said:
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER `pm_sales_agent_BDEL` BEFORE DELETE ON `pm_sales_ag' at line 1
`

Comment: Nevermind my comment earlier. This is the real error:

`#1419 - You do not have the SUPER privilege and binary logging is enabled (you *might* want to use the less safe log_bin_trust_function_creators variable) `

Comment: Thank you for taking time to answer my questions. The `ON DELETE CASCADE` tip you provided me seemed to be a better solution than creating triggers. However, I have some triggers that just don't use that "delete" part and has something to do with the app logic. This being said, I think I would just do an offensive approach on the app-code itself instead of relying on mysql to do such procedures. Although there might be a **slight** response time difference.

Comment: If you wish to ensure data integrity, do everything you can on database level. Other business logic is debatable, if it should be done on database or application level. Can't decide that for you and it's not a good question for stackoverflow. Opinion based answers are not welcome here, facts count, nothing else. If you have another question anyway, feel free to ask another one. It's a Q&A site :)

Comment: I appreciate it. Thank you once again.

Comment: Oh, sorry. Im a newbie. Thanks for the tip :D